# how to find function name only in the dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to print function name which is stored as a value in dictionary.

```
switcher = {
    1: one,
    2: two,
}
for key,value in switcher.items():
    print(key,value)

I want the output to be
1 one
2 two
but it gives 
1 <function one at 0x03541540>
2 <function two at 0x038AF108>
```

Comment: The items inside the dict are functions? You want to print the name of each function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in your logic. However, when you refer function (either one() or two() in your case), it return the memory address and not the readable name of the function. Calling `__name__` attribute of your function object will return you the name of your function.

```
def one():
    print('I am from one')

def two():
    print('I am from two')


switcher = {
    1: one,
    2: two,
}
for key,value in switcher.items():
    print(f'Key: {key} Value: {value.__name__}')
    #optionally to execute current function that was returned by the iterator
    value()
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `__name__` dunder method.

```
switcher = {
    1: one,
    2: two,
}
for key,value in switcher.items():
    print(key,value.__name__)
```